# Usar ItemCommand em C# de uma listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

Estou a trabalhar com uma `ListView` em que apresenta os itens numa lista desordenada e como *links*. Embaixo da `ListView` tem o botão "CRIAR" para inserir um novo item na `ListView`.

Consegui fazer com que, quando edito qualquer item da *list* clicando no *link*, o botão "CRIAR" fique `Enabled = false`, fiz isso utilizando o `ItemCommand` da `ListView` como esta no código abaixo. O problema é que eu queria não permitir que o utilizador faça um editar de outro item quando ele esta a inserir um novo, alguma dica?

O botão "CRIAR" se encontra fora da `ListView`.

```
protected void lvDiagnosticos_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
    {
        criarDiagnostico.Enabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        criarDiagnostico.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: "asp.net" tem relação com a pergunta?

Comment: Sim pois o controlo utilizado é uma ListView e faz parte do ASP.NET,é nesse controlo que é utilizado o commando do SQL

Answer (score 1):

Não entendi 100% o processo de inserir um item novo que está utilizando, mas aparentemente me parece que bastaria que durante esse processo você alterasse a propriedade `LabelEdit` para `False`.
De todo modo, sugiro também que dê uma olhada no link abaixo, que mostra um controle customizado, que pode te dar mais flexibilidade para o que está procurando.

[In-place editing of ListView subitems.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6646/In-place-editing-of-ListView-subitems)